# MySQL: "Data truncation: Truncated incorrect DOUBLE value"

Tags: java, mysql

I have next code, which works fine locally, but fails on production. I have no access to the production, so can not check a version of mysql library there, but can this be because of old version? Any other ideas?


From production: com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlDataTruncation: Data truncation: Truncated incorrect DOUBLE value: '28640,28643'

```
        String update = "UPDATE ...WHERE INT_ID IN (?)"
        String ids = "28640,28643";
        pstmt.setString(1, ids);
```

Comment: placeholders represent SINGLE values. you cannot provide multiple values for an `IN` like that. in fact, `in()` searches are one place placeholders barf all over themselves. you have to build a dynamic statement and put in a placeholder for EVERY value you want to put into the `in()`.

Comment: thx, will try. But interesting why it works locally?)

Comment: depends on sql strict mode and whatnot. mysql is usually forgiving of type mismatches and tries the best it can to do what it THINKS you want.